# Custom bitmap transformation method with Picasso

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I have a function which takes in a bitmap as a parameter, and return a bitmap.

```
public Bitmap setRoundedCornes(Bitmap b, int l, int r, int t, int b)
```

Before using Picasso, I used this method before my final bitmap was used in the app.

Now I'm using Picasso and am unsure how to apply this method.

Does anyone have any idea?

**EDIT**

I now have:

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int topLeftX, int topLeftY, int topRightX, int topRightY, int bottomRightX, int bottomRightY, int bottomLeftX, int bottomLeftY) {
    try {
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        // the float array passed to this function defines the x/y values of the corners
        // it starts top-left and works clockwise
        // so top-left-x, top-left-y, top-right-x etc
        RoundRectShape rrs = new RoundRectShape(new float[]{topLeftX, topLeftY, topRightX, topRightY, bottomRightX, bottomRightY, bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY}, null, null);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        rrs.resize(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        rrs.draw(canvas, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }catch(Exception e){

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyTransform implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        //your logic to transform goes here
        return getRoundedCornerBitmap(source, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for transformation which implements Transformation

for e.g.

```
public class MyTransform implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

    int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

    Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
    if (squaredBitmap != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
            BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    float r = size / 2f;
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

    squaredBitmap.recycle();
    return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```

now to apply this transformation you can use picasso like this

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(url)
    .transform(new MyTransform())
    .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                              // do something if its loaded successfully
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                             // do something if its not loaded successfully
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: where is the `key()` used?

Comment: from the docs   `key()
Returns a unique key for the transformation, used for caching purposes.`

Comment: https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Transformation.html

Comment: I receive the following error - `Transformation circle mutated input Bitmap but failed to recycle the original.`

Comment: If you return a new Bitmap then you need to call recycle() on the original.

Comment: you need to use two bitmaps, and recycle the one you are not returning. i am updating my code plz check if you need to make it a circle

Comment: You're code works but I can't seem to apply this to my function... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can apply Transformation like this one:

```
public class CropSquareTransformation implements Transformation {
  @Override public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
    int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
    if (result != source) {
      source.recycle();
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override public String key() { return "square()"; }
}
```

See Picasso documentation

Comment: where is the `key()` used?

Comment: I receive the following error - `Transformation circle mutated input Bitmap but failed to recycle the original.`